# Aligning 3 divs in LI tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking a `bootstrap way` to solve it but somehow not successful hence tried css one but it's producing thing like:

[image]

As you can see `123` is going out of list.

My code is given below:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
        <div class=".col-lg-2 pull-left">1</div>
        <div class=".col-lg-8 pull-left">2</div>
        <div class=".col-lg-4 pull-left">3</div>
</li>
```

*JS Fiddle*

http://jsfiddle.net/6bszgn85/

Comment: Please remove the "dot" (`.`) in `class` attribute.

Comment: Markup is wrong. You have used . in class name within HTML

Comment: k, I did, but nothing made any difference. It's happening due to `list-group-item`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and post it?

Comment: @Benya16 http://jsfiddle.net/6bszgn85/

Comment: Would request you to post your relevant CSS as well also post your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, `div` inside `li` here is the solution.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="list-group">

    <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="col-lg-2 pull-left">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 pull-left">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left">3</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>   <!-- Just clear the float and everything will be ok-->
    </li>

</ul>
```

Hope this help you.! Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/goe749L0/).**

Comment: Should probably look at the docs on [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic). I think wrapping in a `.row` is the more correct solution.

Comment: Yes. `.row` has the same thing as `.row:after { clear: both; }`.

Comment: `.row` also applies correct margins so that the columns don't wrap incorrectly. `.pull-left` is also redundant on the columns as they are already floated left.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your columns in a row. See docs on [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">3</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=".col-lg-2 pull-left">1</div>
        <div class=".col-lg-8 pull-left">2</div>
        <div class=".col-lg-4 pull-left">3</div>
        </div>
</li>
```

`.col-xx-yy` classes should be wrapped in `.row` class
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bszgn85/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not good idea to use those ul, li... make it just  s

It will make it much more easier :)

Well, maybe use css .. try to make heigher height of the divs :)